# Euler-Lagrange Equation for Kantorovich Dual Problem

Tags: measure-theory, optimal-transportation

Given two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, the Kantorovich Dual problem for quadratic cost is to
$$
\text{minimize} \quad \int \phi(x)d\mu + \int \psi(y)d\nu 
$$
over pairs $(\phi,\psi)\in L^1(d\mu)\times L^1(d\nu)$ such that $xy \leq \phi(x) + \psi(y)$. In Villani's book *Topics in Optimal Transportation*,
P71 section 2.1.6, a variational argument is used to derived the Euler-Lagrange Equation for this problem, which turns out to be 
$$
\nabla \phi_{\#} \mu = \nu.
$$
The author also refers to a paper by Gangbo for the derivation.

In both the book and the paper, it is assume that measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are supported by compact sets. In Gangbo's paper, $\mu$ and $\nu$ are simply the Lebesgue measures.

**My question:** is there an argument for the general case without any assumption on $\mu$ and $\nu$?

Comment: Use the $\sigma$-additivity to approximate $\mu,\nu$ by compactly supported measures?